# Diagram for 'Relay In a Box' (RIB) water sensor

Tags: circuit-design, relay, design

I’m trying to build a water detection sensor that will turn on a small pump to maintain a certain water level.

I found [this video](https://youtu.be/nTM0IVdMpKA) using an RIB21CDC but unfortunately I only have a RIBU1C.

Is there any way to configure this and skip all the siren and light stuff?

It would be even better if I could just splice into the power cord of the pump too, as it’s only temporary.

Comment: If you search "float switch" I think you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: That was my first thought, but unfortunately due to the nature of the project we are unable to use a float switch.

Comment: the relay is just a switch ... all it does is, it touches two wires together to complete a circuit ...  look at the schematic diagram at 0:50 in the video ... there is no reason to have the light or the siren

Comment: which float switch are you unable to use, and why? (there are many different types)

Comment: small pump: how small?

Comment: I can’t use a float switch as it’s an engineering school project and they specifically said no float switch. And as for the relay can I just use the box I was saying?